# Bluetooth headset button problems on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, headset

The problem is that MediaSession.Callback()'s method onMediaButtonEvent() is not called after startBluetoothSco() method call.
So, I use this code:

```
mMediaSession.setCallback(new MediaSession.Callback() {
    public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(@NonNull Intent mediaButtonIntent) {
        Logging.d(TAG, "onMediaButtonEvent");
        return super.onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonIntent);
    }

        public void onPause() {
           Logging.d(TAG, "onPause");
           super.onPause();
        }

        public void onPlay() {
           Logging.d(TAG, "onPlay");
           super.onPlay();
        }

        public void onStop() {
            Logging.d(TAG, "onStop");
            super.onStop();
        }
});
mMediaSession.setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
PlaybackState state = new PlaybackState.Builder()
        .setActions(                PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY | PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE |
                                    PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY_FROM_MEDIA_ID | PlaybackState.ACTION_PAUSE |
                                    PlaybackState.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT | PlaybackState.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS)
        .setState(PlaybackState.STATE_STOPPED, PlaybackState.PLAYBACK_POSITION_UNKNOWN, 0)
        .build();
mMediaSession.setPlaybackState(state);
mMediaSession.setActive(true);
```

onMediaButtonEvent() method is called every time after pressing headset button, but after

```
mAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
```

it is not calling anymore. It will be callable only after

```
mAudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
```

What is the solution to this problem?